# Need to grab input from a form, process it with php, having the option the reload the page depending on the answer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my problem.

I have a startpage website on this address: http://battlestation.rocks/

It mostly revolves around a search bar in the front page that executes commands. Presently, every command is processed with php, like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchBar'])) {
    $originalcommand = $_POST['searchBar'];
    processcommand($originalcommand);
    return;
}
```

With this, every command reloads the page, which is a waste as most of the times it just opens some link from the startpage. In other cases, the startpage is changed by the commands, and thus in those cases I would like the page to reload.

I've seen from other questions that you can have the page not reload with AJAX, but none of the answers I've seen send the form input to php for processing, nor do they include the option to reload if necessary.

I'm very much a hobbyist coder and have zero experience with AJAX, please don't get too technical on me. I'm obsessed with this startpage, I just need to get this working as intended. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP directly then the page needs to reload. If you use AJAX then you can send it so without reloading. !-You need a new PHP file in which you process the input-! An example with jquery but works the same:

You normal site:

```
<form action=''>
        <input type='email' id='email' placeholder='E-Mail' required=""/>
        <input type='password' id='pwd' placeholder='Passwort' required=""/>

        <button id='go_login'>Go</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#go_login').click(function() {

    var bn = $('#email').val();
    var pw = $('#pwd').val();

    $.post('newphpsite.php', {'bn': bn, 'pw': pw}, function(data) {
       alert(data); //send back echo from PHP
    });

   return false; //The form is not sent and does not reload the page.
 });
</script>
```

newphpsite.php :

```
<?php 

  $bn = $_POST['bn'];
  $pw = $_POST['pw'];

  echo $bn."".$pw;

?>
```

?>

Comment: Thanks a lot, you got me really close to solving the problem. Ajax currently gets the input, sends it to php correctly. However, for some reason when the php file tries to execute the appropriate action, it does not recognize commands from other php files it is linked to. The error I get is: "Fatal error: call to undefined function". So if I let php handle the entire input, it works, if it gets the input from ajax, it doesn't. What gives, any idea?

Comment: forget about it, I solved that problem. It's still not quite working but I'm back in my element. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the delay in replying, I didn't have much free time these last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should send the data via AJAX.  One popular option is to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).  Below is a simplified example using jQuery.

First, the HTML:

```
 <input id="searchBar" name="searchBar" type="text" /> 
 <button id="submit">Search</button>
 <div id="searchResults"></div>
```

Next the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "search.php", // Your PHP file
            data: {
                searchBar:  $("#searchBar").val()
            },
            success:function(results) {
                 // Do something with your results
                 $("#searchResults").html(results);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```